# Opening a leaflet popup on a layerGroup

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to draw country shapes on a leaflet map using `L.GeoJSON(data).addTo(map)`. I then want to bind a popup to the click event of that country shape...

```
new L.GeoJSON(data, {
  onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    layer['on']('click', popupFunction);
  }
}).addTo(this.map);


popupFunction = function(event) {
  var layer = event.target;

  // Open the 'add' popup and get our content node
  var bound = layer.bindPopup(
    "<div>Hello World!</div>"
  ).openPopup();

  // Ugly hack to get the HTML content node for the popup
  // because I need to do things with it
  var contentNode = $(bound['_popup']['_contentNode']);
}
```

Now this works fine when the data is a single polygon, because then the `layer` attribute passed to the onEachFeature function is just that: a layer.

However if the `data` is a multipolygon (i.e. the US) this stops working because the "`layer`" is now a layerGroup (it has a `_layers`) attribute and therefore has no `_popup` attribute and so I can't get the `_contentNode` for the popup.

It seems like this should be quite a common thing, wanting a popup on a layerGroup. Why does it have no `_popup` attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

short answer: layergroup does not support popup

plan B:

you should consider using [FeatureGroup](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#featuregroup), it extends [LayerGroup](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup) and has the bindPopup method and this is an example

```js
L.featureGroup([marker1, marker2, polyline])
    .bindPopup('Hello world!')
    .on('click', function() { alert('Clicked on a group!'); })
    .addTo(map);
```

Comment: if this solved your question please set it as the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

You cannot bind a L.Popup to anything else than a L.Layer because the popup will some coordinates to anchor on.

For a L.Marker it will be the position (L.Latlng), for the L.Polygon it will be the center (look at [the code](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/layer/vector/Polygon.js) to see how it is calculated).

As for the other cases (like yours), you can open a popup but you will have to decide where the popup opens:

```
var popup = L.popup()
    .setLatLng(latlng)
    .setContent('<p>Hello world!<br />This is a nice popup.</p>')
    .openOn(map);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should be able to bind popUp in similar way to [Using GeoJSON with Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html) tutorial. Something like this:

```
var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson(data, {
  onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    layer.bindPopup('<div>Hello World!</div>');
  }
}).addTo(map);
```

How to further process your popUps depends on your usecase. Maybe this can be enough for you:

```
geoJsonLayer.eachLayer(function(layer) {
  var popUp = layer._popup;
  // process popUp, maybe with popUp.setContent("something");
});
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to open all popups in a layer group:

```
markers.eachLayer(marker => marker.openPopup());
```

While dealing with layer groups, you might want to consider passing `{ autoClose: false, closeOnClick: false }` options while binding popup, so popups won't get closed while opening new popup, or if user clicks on the map:

```
marker.bindPopup(item.name, { autoClose: false, closeOnClick: false });
```